# Dataset deserialization to object issue - vb .net

Tags: vb.net, dataset, deserialization

Hi everyone i'm having some trouble deserializing a dataset (with parent table) to the correspondent object.
Every table have is array object inside his parent object for deserialization, every array have default {}, but if parent table have no rows the inner object is set to nothing, not empty array... how may i correct this issue?!?

Thanks a lot to everyone.

VB .Net code:

```
Public Function DeserializeDataSetToObj(ByRef DataSetIn As DataSet, ByVal t As Type) As Object
        Dim obj As Object = Nothing
        Dim stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()

        Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream)
            DataSetIn.WriteXml(writer)
        End Using

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

        Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream)
            Try
                Dim xmlSer As System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer = New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(t)
                obj = xmlSer.Deserialize(reader)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Using

        Return obj
    End Function
```

Objects Class

```
<Serializable(), XmlRoot("MainDataset"), XmlType("MainDataset")>
Public Class MainDataset

        <XmlElement("Header1")>
        Public Property Header1() as HeaderType

        <XmlElement("Header2")>
        Public Property Header2() as HeaderType
End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class HeaderType

        <XmlElement("Rows")>
        Public Property Rows() as RowType
End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class RowType

        <XmlElement("ColumnA")>
        Public Property ColumnA as String

        <XmlElement("ColumnB")>
        Public Property ColumnB as String

        <XmlElement("ColumnC")>
        Public Property ColumnC as String
End Class
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema id="MainDataset" xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" name="MainDataset">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Header1">          
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Rows">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ColumnA" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ColumnB" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ColumnC" type="xs:string"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

                <xs:element name="Header2">          
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Rows">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ColumnA" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ColumnB" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ColumnC" type="xs:string"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more about exactly what is your end goal here?  Seems to me you're simply trying to convert the contents of a dataset to an object.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a dataset in this why: -HeaderTable1 RowTable1 -HeaderTable2 RowTable2 in the object i have 2 array (HeaderTable1, HeaderTable2) with within a RowTable1, 2 Array each with default value {} If the input dataset only have rows on Header Tables and not in Rows Table my inner RowTable array is deserialized as "Nothing", not the default value {}. If possible i want to have de default one

Comment: Ok, but what is you expected output.  Going by your code here it looks like all your trying to achieve is simply convert a dataset to an object.  What is that object?  Why go through the process of  serialsizing the dataset via WriteXml just to deserialsize it again?

Comment: i did not found a better way to convert it

Comment: I have edited main post with class and xsd examples

Comment: Still seems like a complicated solution.  Why not just simply use the dataset?  Why go through all the trouble of converting it at all?   The dataset is after all an object

Comment: The dataset have ton of overhead and the achievement is to not use at all the dataset after the first transition time...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved... if i use list instead array i receive an empty list not a nothing object.
Thanks to everyone